# Extract date and time from text using SAS

Tags: full-text-search, text-files, sas

I have something like this, which is in .txt format.

> 'random title'
>
> random things , 00:00 AM, 1 January
>
> 2005, 555 words, (English)
>
> 'random long title'
>
> random things , 00:00 AM, 1 January 2005, 111 words,
>
> (English)

The time and date need to be extracted in the format yyyymmdd and hhmm.
I tried to use comma as the delimiter.

```
DATA News;
  INFILE 'C:xxxx/xxxx/xxxx' DLM',';
  INPUT Title $75. Time $10. Date $20. Words $15. Lang $10.;
PROC PRINT DATA=News;
  TITLE 'Time and Date';
  VAR Time Date;
RUN;
```

But it failed, those entries contain multiple lines and also are not well-formatted.

Are there any solutions?

Comment: What have you tried? http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: It would help if you provided more context for what you are trying to do. It sounds like you need to extract dates and times from unstructured text. SAS might not be the best tool for that. Does your solution have to be completely SAS, or is it sufficient if SAS is the final output? You could look in to SAS input and scan.

Comment: Your question is not at all clear. Please show what you have tried and what output you expect.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I had added the code I tried. I am a extreme newbie. Sorry for the inconvenience caused.

Comment: @AaronKurtzhals Thanks. Tools other than SAS is also fine. All I want is to extract dates and times from random texts in the format yyyymmdd and hhmm. The main problem is that those entries are in multiple lines.

Answer (score 1):

If your dates are always formatted like so:
00:00 AM, 1 January 2005

Then you can use a perl regular expression to find them.

```
data test;
input @;
_prx = prxparse('/\d\d:\d\d (?:AM|PM), \d{1,2} (?:January|February|March) \d{4}/');
start = 1;
stop = length(_infile_);
call prxnext(_prx, start, stop, _infile_, position, length);
   do while (position > 0);
      found = substr(_infile_, position, length);
      put found= position= length=;
      call prxnext(_prx, start, stop, _infile_, position, length);
   end;
datalines;
'random title'
random things , 00:00 AM, 1 January
2005, 555 words, (English)
'random long title'
random things , 00:00 AM, 1 January 2005, 111 words,
(English)
;;;;
run;
```

Then use the FOUND value as you would normally with a SAS character variable to obtain date and time, or datetime, information.  Obviously extend my short list of months to contain all twelve months.

That finds the second example, but not the first (which is not reasonably findable using datalines in an example); but if you are not using datalines, but instead a text file, you could manipulate the record format to remove the line feed and carriage return and thus see both as a single record (and thus match).  Look into `RECFM=N` for more details on that.

Comment: @FredNg would you edit your question and explain the result of when you tried Joe's code?